# Why isn't Minecraft letting me eat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I try to eat it won't let me. It only used my pork as a Weapon. I reset my settings to default.

Comment: Your mouse buttons are probably switched. Go tonthe control settings and change it.

Answer (score 1):

The game does not let you eat if you are not hungry. In creative mode, the hunger bar is hidden, but the value of your actual hunger still exists and the game does not let you eat if it is not smaller than the maximum value. You will get more hungry by doing physical activity like fighting or digging, so go destroy or kill something, then you will be able to eat.

Comment: I have a feeling that when I played Minecraft, long ago, you would only lose hunger if your difficulty was set to one that allowed for monsters.

Comment: @PlanetAlexander Peacefull difficulty let you get hungry but you can not die on hungler like usaly.

Answer (score 0):

You can only eat food if you are hungry (with the exception of foods that grant you any form of positive or negative buff - such as spider eyes or golden apples).

In survival (and hardcore) gamemodes, you can see the hunger right of your health, illustrated using a bit of meat on a bone. As soon as you loose any of this hunger - the game allows you to eat.

You can loose hunger the following ways:

- Regenerating Health*
- Sprinting*
- Fighting/mining/using most tools
- Having the "hunger" effect**

(* only possible when the user has a certain amount of hunger already)

(** attained usually when eating rotten flesh)

Finally, you cannot loose hunger in spectator or creative modes, so don't be in either of those mods (not to mention that you are unable to see your hunger in creative).

---

(To cover what was said above:)

If for some reason your keys have been rebound, you should go into settings to bind them correctly. The "Eat" key is the same as the following:

- Blocking with your sword (or shield)
- Placing Blocks
- Placing/Collecting Fluids with a bucket
- Using bonemeal

So if you can still do any of those - then it's unlikely that you have bound it to the wrong key.

---

Answer (score 0):

According to the Minecraft Wiki link posted here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Hunger#.

Here is a quote from the Minecraft Wiki page called: "Hunger"

> Your hunger meter is shown in the heads-up display in the form of the hunger bar, which is located opposite from the health bar and represented by 10 drumsticks.

Another quote from the link above:

> The hunger value does not drain on Peaceful mode.

So now my question for you: is your difficulty on **Peaceful**?